# CSS Animation not working in safari web browser even after adding -webkit

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, safari

I have been trying to change the CSS animation duration via the following code:

```
.button{
   -webkit-animation-name: effect;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.05s; 
}

@keyframes effect {
   0% { opacity: 0.0; 
   50% { opacity: 0.5; }
   100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

and

```
 $('.button').css("-webkit-animation-duration",  "3s" );
```

It's working in both Chrome and Firefox (by using -moz-animation-duration) but not in Safari, even if I have the -webkit- prefix.

Thank you :)

Comment: Why are not you using animation-duration directly?

Comment: @orabis I have tried that as well, and it is working on all browsers except Safari.

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle link or demo?

Comment: do you have a keyframe for the animation?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri Yes, I do have a keyframe.

Comment: @Alisinna cn you please post your keyframe code?

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I have shown more code as requested :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-delay: -2s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
    50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
    75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
    100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Using negative values: Here, the animation will start as if it had already been playing for 2 seconds:</p>

<button type="button">Go</button>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and how this answer the question ? he cleary said `even if I have the -webkit- prefix.`

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, it is not suitable for solving my problem. My problem is that I would like to change the CSS animation duration whenever a particular action is performed using Javascript. In my case a button is pressed and -webkit-animation-duration should change.